# Happlink Plug-up FIDO U2F Security Key. Why it doesnt work immediately in Ubuntu

Tags: usb, two-factor-authentication

Ubuntu 12.04LTS 
Happlink Plug-up FIDO U2F Security Key. Why it doesn't work immediately in Ubuntu.
[http://sk.happlink.com/plugup/en/](https://web.archive.org/web/20160916203036/http://sk.happlink.com/plugup/en/)
What shall I do with it?

Answer (score 3):

After doing the changes, just triggering udevadm wasn't enough.

I also needed to do

```
sudo service udev restart
```

For reference, this is my working configuration:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2581", ATTRS{idProduct}=="f1d0", MODE="0660", GROUP="PUT YOUR USERGROUP HERE"

KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2581"
```

Comment: It looks like an answer... Is it one?

Comment: Why don't you think this is an answer? I just came here from review and it sure looks like an answer. FYI "Had to post this as an answer 'cause I'm not allowed to comment" Not having the rep to comment does not mean you can use the answer section for comments, that will get you downvoted fast but I don't see how this is not an answer? Can you elaborate on why?

Comment: @markkirby it is basically bruni's answer with an addition

Answer (score 1):

This answer is from the page you linked yourself to (In the FAQ section, though it is not properly translated). I have not tested it and I am not able to do so as I have no such key.

To use your key in Linux, you must change the access rights to allow your account to access it. To do this, simply add a udev rule to the card. Create a file named /etc/udev/rules.d/10-security-key.rules with this content:

```
SUBSYSTEMS == "usb", ATTRS idVendor {} == "2581" ATTRS idProduct {} == "f1d0", MODE = "0660", GROUP = "un_de_vos_groupes"
```

You can specify any of the groups used by your account. For a list of your groups, use the Linux groups command. Once the udev rule is added, restart udev by typing

```
sudo udevadm trigger
```

in a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T).

Comment: Thanx Bruni for your replay. But that content didnt work. I google that staff :  SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2581", TAG+="uaccess", TAG+="udev-acl"     and it works for me. https://bbs.archlinux.de/viewtopic.php?id=27397

Comment: Open terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T). Then type or paste this content: <sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/10-security-key.rules>  Next step: <SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2581", TAG+="uaccess", TAG+="udev-acl"> to write it use "Ctrl+O" and then exit by "Ctrl+X". The last step type: <sudo udevadm trigger> and close  terminal.  Sorry for detailed comment.